# How to reference a control from a module?

Tags: database, vb.net, textbox, reference

Forgive me about the title, I have no idea what this is called.

I have a MS Access database set up, with a `Period` field that has either values 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. I retrieve these values using a database connection and I would like to reference a particular control based on what period was grabbed from the database.

Here's example code, pseudo of course.

```
TextBox(dr(3)).Text = dr(0)
```

`dr(3)` contains the period, and dr(0) contains the content I would like to put into the text box. I have these text boxes on my form: `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, `TextBox3`, `TextBox4` and `TextBox5`.

So if `dr(3)` contained `2` then I would want to reference `TextBox2`.

I hope I've made myself clear, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your textboxes are on the same control (ie-they have the same parent object). You could use:

```
Dim txtbox as TextBox = CType(parentControl.FindControl("TextBox" & dr(3).ToString()), TextBox)
txtBox.Text = dr(0)
```

Edit: For groupbox

```
For each ctrl as Control in myGB.Controls
    If ctrl.ID = "TextBox" & dr(3).ToString() Then
        CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = dr(0)
        'EDIT: add exit to stop iteration once the textbox is found
        Exit For  
    End If
Next
```

Comment: They're all grouped in a GroupBox yeah, I'll give this a go now and get back to you :D

Comment: After using this code: `CType(Main.gridHolder.FindControl`, I get the erorr: `'FindControl' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox'.` is it okay to just try and find it through the entire form? It is unlikely that there will be any more textboxes with the same kind of name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty in VBA but you probably want to use a control array. When a control is set up as a control array you can index that array using dr(3).